# Prove $\sum^{\infty}_{n=k} (-1)^{n} \frac 1 {n^r} \le |\frac 1 {k^r}|$ for a natural number $r \ge 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Prove $\sum^{\infty}_{n=k} (-1)^{n} \frac 1 {n^r}  \le |\frac 1 {k^r}|$ for a natural number $r \ge 1$

I know the above series converge since $a_n > a_{n+1}>0$.

I have $\sum^{k}_{n=k} (-1)^{n} \frac 1 {n^r} \le (-1)^{k}\frac 1 {k^r}| \le | \frac 1 {k^r}|$, but applying the induction hypotheses that $s_N = \sum^{N}_{n=k} (-1)^{n} \frac 1 {n^r} \le | \frac 1 {k^r}|$ for $N \ge k$ doesn't seem to work out.

In general is the following true ?

> Prove $|\sum^{\infty}_{n=k} (-1)^{n}a_n | \le |a_k|$ if $a_n \ge a_{n+1}$ and $a_n \rightarrow 0$ for $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

If $a_n\ge a_{n+1}>0$ for all $n$ then
$$\displaylines{
  a_k-a_{k+1}<a_k\cr
  a_k-a_{k+1}+a_{k+2}=a_k-(a_{k+1}-a_{k+2})\le a_k\cr}$$
and so on; also
$$\displaylines{
  a_k-a_{k+1}\ge0\cr
  a_k-a_{k+1}+a_{k+2}=(a_k-a_{k+1})+a_{k+2}>0\cr}$$
and so on.  Hence
$$0\le a_k-a_{k+1}+a_{k+2}-\cdots\pm a_K\le a_k$$
for all $K$.  But
$$\sum_{n=k}^K (-1)^n a_n=\pm(a_k-a_{k+1}+a_{k+2}-\cdots\pm a_K)\ ,$$
so
$$-a_k\le\sum_{n=k}^K (-1)^n a_n\le a_k\ .$$
Hence
$$\biggl|\sum_{n=k}^\infty (-1)^n a_n\biggr|\le a_k$$
provided the sum converges.

Comment: You need also show $-a_k \le$ for the inequality to be true ?

Comment: That comment makes no sense as it stands, there is something missing.

Comment: I mean you take the absolute value. You know the sum is less than $a_k$, but you also need to show it is greater than $-a_k$ for the absolute value to hold ?

Comment: Showing the sum is greater than or equal to $-a_k$ is almost identical, see updated answer for the details.

Comment: Thank you David. You just "silently" threat the case when you can't pair of terms, because there is an uneven number of terms after $a_k$ ?

Comment: Perhaps you can work this out for yourself by reading my answer carefully.  **Hint**.  I gave *two* cases for the upper bound, and also two for the lower bound.